# Removing extra space between two containers

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

As a beginner in Web design, I am doing an assignment where I need output of page like this using Bootstrap:

[image]

While doing assignment, for most part I am done, but getting extra spaces between header ***About US*** and `<hr>` above Our History, but so far unsuccessful. You can preview my code at: [https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/](https://jsfiddle.net/q9myefy8/)

For preview, this is the output page I have until now:

[image]

So any leads would be appreciated.

Comment: You should use the inspector on your web browser "f12", it helps a lot. You would instantly know that it's because of `.row-content : min-height: 400px;`

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are setting the min-height of **content-row** to 400px thats why you are having the extra space

you need to remove it to fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Remove min-height :400px from .row-content

```
.row-content{
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding: 50px 0px 50px 0px;
    border-bottom: 1px ridge;
    /* min-height: 400px;*/
}
```

JS fiddle for reference
https://jsfiddle.net/Nagasai_Aytha/q9myefy8/1/